# Putting noindex into header, getting white screen

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add noindex,follow to all archives, a few different pages and the 404 page in my WP site, but wherever I try to place this:

```
if($paged > 1 || is_404 || is_page(array( 1110,1115, 1114 )){
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
}
```

I get a white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a white screen because there is an error in the code. Your brackets don't balance.

```
if($paged > 1 || is_404 || is_page(array( 1110,1115, 1114 ))) {
//                                                          ^ need another
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much! Could you please tell me though how I can make the page number on paginated pages be shown BEFORE the sitename so like this:  category | page 2 | mysite   ?